# a:active on asp.net C# web

Tags: css

What I am trying to accomplish is creating a feature for a solid line on click on my navigational menu bar. I have tried to use this code:

```
div.menu ul li a:active
{
    text-decoration:none !important; 
    background-color: white;
    color: #999999;
    text-decoration:none !important; 
    border-bottom: thick outset White;
}


div.menu ul li a:visited
{
    display: inline;
    line-height: 13.6px;
    padding: 4px 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration:none !important; 
    border-bottom: thick outset White !important;
}
```

It works on my hover:

```
div.menu ul li a:hover
{
    color: White;
    text-decoration:none !important; 
    border-bottom: thick outset White;
}
```

So the probable issue is that it's a browser problem. Does anyone have a solution? an example would be nice.

Comment: works on my machine: http://jsfiddle.net/cUn9H/ I used firefox 15, what browser did you use? or is it an inherit issue with other css?

Comment: Lol, took the effort to make a working sample, to show that it is valid CSS and got 4 downvotes!

Comment: That's a shame I can't downvote. It seems I made a mistake on my question probably will get downvoted as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with my code is that I am using a generated asp:menu item. Instead of using ul ,li, and a tags. If I have used it from the start I wouldn't confuse myself with server side code and client side code.